# Warning: mysql_num_rows() in search engine coding

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, rows

I'm trying to create a (very basic) search engine and I keep getting an error that I can't seem to fix.

**Warning**: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in **/home/a6057614/public_html/music/search.php** on line **35**

My coding looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8" />
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Search Engine</h2>
    </form action="search.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="k" size="50" value="<?php echo $_GET['k']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <hr />
    <?php
        $k = $_GET['k'];
        $terms = explode(" ", $k);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

        foreach ($terms as $each){
            $i++;
            if ($i == 0)
                $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
            else
                $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";


        }

        // connect
        mysql_connect("webhost", "user", "pass");
        mysql_select_db("search");

        $query = mysql_query($query);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows > 0){

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];

                echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
                $description<br /><br />";
            }

        }
        else
            echo "No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";

        //disconnect
        mysql_close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-injections. Please learn how to use prepared statements and use `mysqli_` or PDO. `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you Stefano, I'll look into it! I'm very new to these things so all tips are extremely helpful.

Comment: As @StefanoSanfilippo sayed mysql_* is deprecated and there is no point of searching solution for this problem, try to convert your code to PDO or mysqli, if you would have any problems don't hesitate to write here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're incrementing `i` at the wrong place in your `for` loop, so the query is appearing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM search WHERE OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ...
```

Change your code to the following:

```
foreach ($terms as $each){
    if ($i == 0)
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, danmullen. I did as you suggested, but I'm still finding an error in my coding. The error is on the same line of coding: $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

Comment: Is $_GET['k'] definitely set to something?  If that variable doesn't contain anyting, then the query will be `SELECT * FROM search WHERE `

Comment: Before `$query = mysql_query($query);`, add `echo $query; exit;` - this will display the query on your screen.  Please post that query here.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `SELECT * FROM search WHERE keywords LIKE '%google%'`

Answer (score 0):

After testing the code with danmullen's tweaks applied, there is nothing wrong that would generate the error you're seeing. That means the only thing left is that your connection information is wrong.

Change this

`mysql_connect("webhost", "user", "pass");`

to this

`mysql_connect("webhost", "user", "pass") or die('Unable to connect to MySQL server');`

and change this

`mysql_select_db("search");`

to this

`mysql_select_db("search") or die('Unable to select database');`